# Configuring jest for code coverage when code is symlinked in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-coverage, jestjs

I am attempting to restructure a Node project using Jest for testing.  Initially, I had all of my `.js` and `.test.js` files in the same directory, and all was well in the world— *i.e.* `jest --coverage` did what I expected.

I've changed my directory structure now, and testing works, but my coverage reporting does not.

Here is my directory structure, edited to remove `node_modules` *except* for a symlink to my `lib` folder.  I am following [this hint](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#avoiding-) for `requiring` my module by symlink.

```
❯ tree
.
├── README.md
├── build
│   └── index.js
├── jest.config.js
├── lib
│   ├── path.js
│   ├── pen.js
│   ├── section.js
│   ├── sprite.js
│   └── utilities.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── itch <= symlink to my `lib` folder
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── env
    │   └── foo.html
    ├── path.test.js
    ├── pen.test.js
    ├── section.test.js
    ├── sprite.test.js
    └── utilities.test.js
```

Here is my `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["**/lib/**/*.js", "**/test/**/*.js"]
};
```

and here is my `scripts` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "mkdir -p ./dist && browserify index.js --standalone Itch > ./dist/itch.js"
}
```

`npm test` works, except my code coverage report is all `0`, as:

```
Test Suites: 5 passed, 5 total
Tests:       38 passed, 38 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.316s
Ran all test suites.
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files     |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                |
 path.js      |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 109,111,115 |
 pen.js       |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 106,107,113 |
 section.js   |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 89,90,92,95 |
 sprite.js    |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 200,202,205 |
 utilities.js |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 55,57,58,62 |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

But when I return to the `.js` and `.test.js` files being in the same directory, my code coverage is `100%`.

I assume my issue is either with my `collectCoverageFrom` variable and/or my use of a symlink to `require` my modules.

Prompted by [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/98), I also tried adding a `package.json` with the same `name` attribute as my package into my `lib` directory, to no avail.

In order to test the idea that the issue was with the symlink, I also tried removing the symlink and moving my `lib` folder directly into my `node_modules` folder.  Then, when I ran `npm test`, I received all `Unknown` test coverage, *viz.*

```
Test Suites: 5 passed, 5 total
Tests:       40 passed, 40 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.576s
Ran all test suites.
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

So now, I'm a bit stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: I would search for issues in jest related to symlinks, that might lead somewhere.

Comment: @enjoylife Thanks!  Does that mean that at least as it appears to you, this setup is properly configured?